# Build flavors always defaults to command line default on iOS Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

In my project, I have set up build flavor debug and staging. But when I try and run it or build an ios app on iOS it always defaults to the command line default set on the Xcode. It runs fine on android, only problem is with iOS.
Both of this command build for the debug configuration, which is command line default.

```bash
flutter build ios -t lib/main.dev.dart --flavor dev
```

```bash
flutter build ios -t lib/main.staging.dart --flavor staging
```

I have no way of not selecting the default. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue, have you found a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Not yet. Just using xcode to archieve for now.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83704 seems to be the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this to work? I had similar issue. It is to do with the xcode setting as shown below

[image]

Currently I am manually changing this every time I do a build. Looking for an automatic solution

Comment: I have the same issue, I'm using fvm, not sure it it's the cause